# Macbook Air trackpad and keyboard suddenly aren't being detected

Tags: mouse, trackpad

The internal trackpad and keyboard of my MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017, macOS Catalina) have suddenly stopped working. They are not being detected and the Macbook just tells me to connect bluetooth ones. I tried resetting SMC, updating the OS, booting in safe mode, etc. and nothing seems to work. Interestingly though, when I run Apple Diagnostics, the keyboard and trackpad work fine, and Apple Diagnostics doesn't detect any errors, so I don't think the hardware itself is faulty. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?